# Is the term Gaussian distribution the preferred term?

Tags: terminology, probability-distributions

Is "Gaussian" the term preferred over "normal" when speaking of the distribution to which these names have been attached?  Are they both referring to the same thing?

Comment: These are equivalent. Both are correct.

Comment: My impression is that probabilists and statisticians say "normal" and the word "Guassian" is used only by other people.

Comment: My probability theory prof in grad school only used "Gaussian."  He always said, "There's nothing 'normal' about the Gaussian distribution."  Physicists tend to use "Gaussian," too.

Comment: Edwin Jaynes proposed calling it the central distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The terms 'Gaussian distribution' and 'normal distribution' are equally correct and refer to the same distribution - neither is particularly preferred over the other.